# AE1200 Linksys WiFI dongle not detected automatically

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb

I am new to Linux and do not know anything about it.

I have been playing around with various distros (Fedora, Mint, Ubuntu) on a spare computer.  I have a Linksys AE1200 WiFi dongle that I need to use to get internet.  The motherboard in my computer doesn't have wireless chip built into it or anything.  I have learned about ndiswrapper and how that can be used to install Windows drivers.  I have had success with that route.

Some of the distros I have been trying out recognize the dongle without the need to download anything extra, but only after I unplugged it and then plugged it back in.  I restart the computer and the dongle isn't recognized.  I unplug it from the USB port and plug it back in and then it works again.

The most recent versions of Fedora and MX Linux did this without the need to download anything extra.  But why do I have to keep unplugging and plugging the dongle back in?

I know nothing about Linux so if there are some commands or something I need to run in the terminal, I would greatly appreciate a guide or something.

Thanks.

Comment: Try installing a Linux distro *while the dongle is connected*, logging into a WiFi router *before* installing the OS. The installer should find needed files on the internet and make them active.